# Bing Search API - where is the App ID

Tags: php, azure, bing

Trying to make a fast API query to the Bing Search API (via Azure Datamarket).

Can make it work with PHP and the **AccountKey**. This integration is quite slow though (about 1.2s query time compared to <0.5s on bing.com).

Tried to make it faster by querying through javascript. Followed these instructions (http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html).

Problem: Do not have an App ID. Do not understand the section "obtaining an app ID". I've an account on azure and everything, but stuck here. I have an account key, a customer ID, an app Name ... but none of these work.

Where can I find the AppID ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that APP ID is retired. We don’t suggest customer use this method currently. 
Bing Search API has updated to 2.0 and moved to Windows Azure Marketplace.

To authenticate a Bing Search API request with Windows Azure Marketplace, you must obtain an account key. This mode of authentication replaces the AppID used in the Bing Search API 2.0. You can obtain your account key by using either at the [Account Keys](https://datamarket.azure.com/account/keys) page.

Here is test code snippet in PHP:

```
$url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';
$accountkey = '<your_account_key>';
$searchUrl = $url.'Image?$format=json&Query=';
$queryItem = 'Bing';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountkey . ":" . $accountkey)
    )
));
$request = $searchUrl . urlencode( '\'' . $queryItem . '\'');
echo($request);
$response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);
$jsonobj = json_decode($response);
echo('<ul ID="resultList">');
foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $value){                        
    echo('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->MediaURL . '">');
    echo('<img src="' . $value->Thumbnail->MediaUrl. '"></li>');
}
echo("</ul>");
```

We can get more details at [Migration Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248077).

If you want to use APPID, you can see the “Getting An AppID” section of the [guide](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html), it has provided the link [Bing Developer Center](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/) to create an appid.

Click the link, it leads us to a page with Bing servers list, as the figure shows:
[image]

Find the Search API and click the “sign in” sutitle, it leads to the page with your applications list, click button “request a new application id”, fill the form of your basic app information:
[image]

Submit and the browser will redirect to the page with app ids list:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, appreciate it. When I click on "Sign in for high volume customers" I get redirected to http://ssl.bing.com/toolbox/bingsearchapi (it says: "The Bing Search API is now available on the Windows Azure Marketplace") and when I click on "get started", it redirects to https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44 (the Search API overview page). I do not get to the last 2 screenshots you're showing. Again, I need JS, already got it working with PHP, but that's too slow. My Account ID is 'Stefan aus MUC'.

Comment: Try browse the [link](https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/developers/appids) and sign in with live id (school or organization account seems can't sign in in my test). However, as **Bing API 2.0** has migrated to **Bing Search API** in Azure, and `APP ID` will be retired, so you can download the Migration Guide, test with new API which do not need `APP ID` any more.

Comment: tried it. Using a personal live ID instead of organizational does not change anything in my test. Old problem - when I click on http://ssl.bing.com/toolbox/bingsearchapi I get to https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44 - no way to create an App ID. All I want is making queries with javascript. With Google CSE it was done in 10mins.

Comment: I don't get it. Some sources say there are no AppIDs anymore, some say there are. But the only way to make a javascript query is by using an AppID as far as I know ?

Comment: if use pure `javascript` to implement Bing Search, we should use **Web Results Only** API. I found 2 samples about it. [With jQuery](https://github.com/cbenard/jquery-bingsearch) and [Without jQuery](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ec69923-7c5f-4ed5-b200-22f6cccdcb34/how-to-use-js-all-bing-search-api?forum=DataMarket)

Comment: Genius. This worked. Now running the "Without jQuery" Version. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

read the article you liked:

> Getting an AppID 
>   The AppID parameter is a value that enables the API
>   to validate that a request is from a registered Bing application developer.
>
> Getting an AppID is a straightforward process. First, go to the Bing
>   Developer Center and sign in with your Windows Live ID. After signing
>   in, you will be presented with a link to create a new AppID. Click the
>   link, then supply basic information about your application and review
>   the Terms of Use. (For more information, see Appendix: Terms of Use
>   Overview.) After you have supplied the information and reviewed the
>   Terms of Use, you will be presented with an AppID.

Comment: yeah, obviously. But this seems outdated or something, as there is no  "link to create a new AppID" after login, just a redirect to Azure.